In JetBrains IDEs, how can you count the usage frequency of all functions and rank them?

When the cursor is on a function name and Alt+F7 is pressed, JetBrains IDEs count the usage frequency of that function. How can I perform this operation on all functions in the project and get a ranking of their usage frequencies?

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Here is the related request at JetBrains issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-295027
Currently, there are no plans to implement it from IDEA side and a third-party plugin is welcome!
Please describe your use case on why it is necessary to search for most used code in a project right in the mentioned issue to attract attention of JetBrains team
